# Consecutive Coin Flip Counting in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and have encountered an error that I can't seem to debug, no matter what alterations I make. I'm attempting to write a function that allows the user to specify the number of flips and the length of a consecutive streak of coin flips. The program is supposed to count the number of times that the streak (heads or tails) occurs. When I run my current program, I return a value of 1 for both heads and tails:

```
import random

def flip():
    flipValue = random.randint(1,2)
    if flipValue == 1:
        side = "Heads"
    else:
        side = "Tails"
    return side

def nStreak():
    numFlips = int(input("Number of flips:"))
    lengthStreak = int(input("Length of streak:"))
    numRuns = 0
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    numStreakHeads = 0
    numStreakTails = 0
    while numRuns != numFlips:
        side = flip()
        numRuns += 1
        if side == "Heads":
            heads += 1
            if heads == lengthStreak:
                numStreakHeads += 1
        if side == "Tails":
            tails += 1
            if tails == lengthStreak:
                numStreakTails += 1
    print("Number of heads streaks:", numStreakHeads)
    print("Number of tails streaks:", numStreakTails)
```

Comment: You're not tracking anywhere what the last flip was.

Comment: I thought the loop would account for each individual flip, how would I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you're not resetting your counter after you reach lendthStreak. So once, say, heads is equal to lendthStreak it will be greater than lendthStreak every time afterwards, thus you'll always get a result of 1. You want to reset that value after you've encountered a streak. You'll also want to reset your counter once you get a flip of the opposite side (once you flip heads, set tails=0).

```
import random
def flip():
    flipValue = random.randint(1,2)
    if flipValue == 1:
        side = "Heads"
    else:
        side = "Tails"
    return side

def nStreak():
    numFlips = int(input("Number of flips:"))
    lengthStreak = int(input("Length of streak:"))
    numRuns = 0
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    numStreakHeads = 0
    numStreakTails = 0
    while numRuns != numFlips:
        side = flip()
        numRuns += 1
        if side == "Heads":
            heads += 1
            tails = 0
            if heads == lengthStreak:
                numStreakHeads += 1
                heads = 0
        if side == "Tails":
            tails += 1
            heads = 0
            if tails == lengthStreak:
                numStreakTails += 1
                tails = 0
    print("Number of heads streaks:", numStreakHeads)
    print("Number of tails streaks:", numStreakTails)
```

Comment: Your response makes a lot of sense. I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer worked for you, you can click the checkmark to accept my answer.